# How do I refactor a select statement which has subqueries using Sql Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, refactoring

Sometimes, subqueries are good and have their place, as in this code:

```
select x1.test, (select r from table) from ......
```

However, adding in more subqueries produces more handicaps on the query,  like performance problems and reusability issues to name a few/

How would I refactor the sql code below to make it run faster than before...

```
Select f.c1
      ,f.c2
         ,f.c3 As 'c3Id'
         ,p.Value As 'c3'
         ,m.c4 As 'r1'


         ,(Select SUM(t1.table1x)
             From [ap].table1 t1
             Where t1.table1x = 1 
               And f.c1 = t1.c1 
               And f.c2 = t1.c2
               And f.c3 = t1.c3) As 'r2'

         ,(Select SUM(t2.x)
             From [ap].table2 t2
             Where t2.c1 = f.c1
               And t2.c1 = f.c2
               And t2.c3 = f.c3) As 'r3'

         ,(Select SUM(t1.table1x)
             From [ap].table3 t3
             Where t3.table3Turu = 2
               And f.c1 = t3.c1 
               And f.c2 = t3.c2
               And f.c3 = t3.c3) As 'r4'

         ,(Select SUM(t4.x)
             From [ap].table4 t4
             Where t4.c1 = f.c1
               And t4.c1 = f.c2
               And t4.c3 = f.c3) As 'r5'

From [ap].table1 f 
Inner Join [dbo].table5 m On f.c1 = m.col11
Inner Join [dbo].table6 p On f.c3 = p.col22

Where p.xxxx = 'test'
Group By f.c1, f.c2, f.c3, m.c4, p.Value
```

Comment: Is your priority to refactor your query (reduce duplicate code) or improve performance? It's possible that those goals will conflict.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UDF (User Defined Functions) to simplify the code. Include your subquery into a function and send required parameters to this function from your main query. For Example, you can send 3 parameters f.c1, f.c2 and f.c3 to a function say GetSumT1() and use that in the query in place of your sub query.

```
Select f.c1       
,f.c2          
,f.c3 As 'c3Id'          
,p.Value As 'c3'          
,m.c4 As 'r1'            
, GetSumT1(f.c1, f.c2, f.c3) As 'r2'
...
...
```

Comment: Anil: i know UDF but this must be Text Query :(